# Convert hourly time series data frames to multiple data frames of single hours

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have a list of data frames with hourly weather station data over a one year period. I want to split these into data frames where each data frame has data from all the weather stations for the same hourly point in time. So for a year, that would be 24 (hours) * 365 (days) = 8760 data frames. This way I can create plots using data from all weather stations for a specific hour.

This is my approach that takes a very long time to compute. I have a years worth of hourly data for about 300 weather stations so this is a lot of data.

**list_of_station_df:** A list of time series station data frames (hourly)

**list_of_all_hourly_station_df:** List of data frames where each df has data from all weather stations for that hour (keep adding to this in each iteration) that contains the final result

```
# Start by adding the hourly df's for the first station
list_of_all_hourly_station_df = split(list_of_station_df[[1]], list_of_station_df[[1]]$time)

for(station_df in list_of_station_df[-1]) {

  # Get a list of hourly df's for this station (each df will have one row)
  list_of_hourly_station_df <- split(station_df, station_df$time)

  # Merge our list with all the previous hourly data with the above
  list_of_all_hourly_station_df <- mapply(rbind, list_of_all_hourly_station_df, 
  list_of_hourly_station_df, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

 }
```

This works when I only iterate over a few stations i.e `for(station_df in list_of_station_df[2:5])`

But when I try run it for all the stations its takes a long time. Was hoping someone would be able to shorten the computational time of the above. Thank you

Comment: I believe converting all your data frame to a single data frame and filtering/subsetting the time will make this whole process much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it would be better if you keep all your data in one dataframe itself.

```
combine_df <- do.call(rbind, list_of_station_df)
```

You should be able to do most of the things with `combine_df` itself even getting hourly dataframes.

```
list_of_all_hourly_station_df <- split(combine_df, format(combine_df$time, '%Y-%m-%d %H'))
```

`list_of_all_hourly_station_df` would have a dataframe for each hour of the year of all the stations combined.